# Show an item in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I store in an arraylist an object (contact) which has name,number,email.
Then i want to display lets say the name in ScrollPane but i get an error on retrieving it (from my other class).
What im doing wrong?

Heres this part of the code(i get the error in the last line using the ):

```
class GetUserInput implements ActionListener {

        //It's the reactions to the buttons that are pressed
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Add Contact")) {
                Agenda a = new Agenda();
                System.out.println(event);
                String inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your contact name");
                a.setName(inp);
                String inp1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your contact number");
                a.setPhoneNumber(inp1);
                String inp2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your contact email");
                a.setEmail(inp2);
                contacts.add(a);
            } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Edit Contact")) {
                String inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the contact you wish to edit ");

            } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Show All Contacts")) {

                System.out.println(a.getName());
```

Comment: What error? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses. Also take a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it, because `a` is created in another block. You can't access it in the last `else if`-block before creating and assigning a new Variable `a`.

Comment: Thanks!
I added this 
for (int x=0; x<contacts.size(); x++){
Object a = contacts.get(x);
textArea.append((String) a);
}

Now its working and i get everything on the screen